# Have you heard Gokigen Naname?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

> Here is a regular **Gokigen Naname** a.k.a **Slalom** a.k.a **Slant** puzzle.
>   An online (mobile-friendly) version is available [here](https://puzz.link/p?gokigen/10/10/j5bi82828dgbcbg7273871826172bbic2617183683727cgdbbg63728di6bh).

[image]

> **Rules**:
>
> - Put a slash (diagonal line) on each cell.
> - Each number in a circle denotes the number of slashes touching it.
> - The slashes should not form a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complete (Hello, it's me, I'm back!)

> [image]

Insights:

> 1) When you see two adjacent '3's, They must be two back to back T-shapes (see that on row 4)
>  
>  2) When you see two '1's on opposite corners of the same square, the slant must not connect the '1's.
>  
>  3) When you make a sure line for an '1', the figure surrounding the '1' will resemble a power button (yeah, give some imagination)

Comments:

A very fun puzzle! Finally got my brain turning after my long break from PSE... ;)

Comment: Nicely solved, well done! Checkmark will be given soon~ and also, welcome back O.K.! :D

Answer (score 4):

Same answer:

> [image: slant]

Tip:

> The $1$ on the very right of row 7 removes an option for it's penultimate $3$, and so both of the lines left of the $3$ can be filled.