# Simon Tatham's Gokigen Naname

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sub>*[Lately](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/97701/28719), I've been interested in **Gokigen Naname** a.k.a **Slalom** a.k.a **Slant**. Luckily, [Simon Tatham](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/) has a generator for Slant. Usually, the generated puzzle is so-so, but this particular generated puzzle amused me as it has a nice solving path (without guessing of course.) Then I decide to share the puzzle to you.*</sub>

---

[image]

> **Rules**:
>
> - Put a slash (diagonal line) on each cell.
> - Each number in a circle denotes the number of slashes touching it.
> - The slashes should not form a loop.

An online (mobile-friendly) version is available [here](https://puzz.link/p?gokigen/12/10/g1bjbh6d2dgd27c66bg2d7113b22613118cg2cbk27263b1161d32cbbg28bh61bg326cg6bi6b).

Comment: Do you have a game ID that we can use for Simon Tatham's Slant? You can find it in the "Game" menu under "Specific..."

Comment: Transcribed it myself: `12x10:a11f1d1a3b23c3b22a2b1a1a1c23b2a1131b221a13113a2c22b1g22a21a31b111a13b322b1b1c23a1d1a11c321a2c1a1e1a1`

Comment: Thanks, @Magma! Apparently I forgot to include that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution:

> [image]

---

### Step by step:

(This is the first time I've tried to solve one of these, so sorry if my explanations and/or logic are confusing or in a weird order and if my terminology is weird :) )

1:

> [image]
>
> Adjacent threes must have lines away from each other as so, which complated a one. The one bottom right must have a line into it as so.

2:

> [image]
>
> Two ones, diagonally adjacent and not on the edge, cannot go into each other without forcing a closed loop around the two ones, so all diagonally adjacent ones have a line between as so.

3:

> [image]
>
> Completed dots can now have the cells around filled in as it is known the slashes don't go into the dots. This completes some more dots.

4:

> [image]
>
> Closing off the completed three, completes a one, which when closed off means a slash goes into the one on the left. When this gets closed off, it completes some of the surrounding twos.

5:

> [image]
>
> Closing off some more twos creates some more completed dots which can then also be closed off.

6:

> [image]
>
> The three cannot go into the 1 without forcing two lines into a one to close off a completed two further down. So the slant must be the other way, which completes a 3 which causes other completions when being closed off.

7:

> [image]
>
> Closing off the completed two, completes a one, and by closing that one off the bottom right can be completed.

8:

> [image]
>
> The almost completed three top right cannot go into the one as closing off will cause a fourth line to go into the three. Therefore it must go into the two, causing a chain of completions via closing off.

9:

> [image]
>
> Some simple deductions regarding avoidance of loops can be made bottom left, and further up to the left a completed two can be closed off to complete the lower left side.

10:

> [image]
>
> The only solution to the bottom left now is as so.

11:

> [image]
>
> The only solution to the bottom right (the key here is to avoid loops as there are a lot of potential ones) is as so.

12 (final):

> [image]
>
> The ones top left cannot go into each other without causing three lines into a two, so must be separated. This causes some closing off which completes some twos and from here, we can complete the rest!

Comment: From step 3 to 4: How do you fill the 1 in row 5/col 4? I am stuck at a similar situation and cannot think of a way to solve that spot.

Comment: @daw I'll be honest, I can't remember. I probably played around a lil and found that was the only scenario that worked, but it took a while to solve and I only saved the pictures, and didn't save my notes this time. Sorry :)

Comment: Well done, checkmark awarded! For step 3 to 4, actually there are some deductions which can be made on the left middle-bottom part, e.g. the three and the collection of ones. After that I recall you can start deducing from bottom to top on the left side then have the similar result. (I'm on mobile so I couldn't give the specific path, but that's the idea).